# Magento open a site in new tab by javascript

Tags: javascript, magento, tabs

How can i opens a new tab in magento using javascript to call a other site?
When i use this, a new window opens:

```
var w = window.open('/offerte/<?php echo $debiteur ;?>.pdf','_blank','fullscreen=yes');
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to open the url in a new tab as the code is running?

Giving _tab creates a new tab.

```
var w = window.open('/offerte/<?php echo $debiteur ;?>.pdf','_tab','fullscreen=yes');
```

Same

```
window.open("http://www.youraddress.com","_self")
```

New tab

```
window.open("http://www.youraddress.com","_tab")
```

I hope any of the examples can help you out with this problem.